# Proper way of dividing CMakeLists to subprojects

Tags: cmake

What's the idiomatic way to have a few libraries and a few executables which are interdependent, in a single `cmake` project, and have `cmake` compute the interlibrary dependencies, and generate non recursive makefiles, so that empty compilation will be fast (at least for unix).

This [example](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html) seems outdated, doesn't really work in recent cmake, and seem to generate recursive makefile.

Comment: What do you mean by _empty compilation_ and why do you insist on non-recursive Makefiles?

Comment: @kynan, empty compilation - issuing `make` when nothing is changed to the project. I require that this would take less than 1 second. With recursive make it can take even 5 seconds and this is unacceptable in my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CMake FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_generate_recursive_Makefiles.3F) generating recursive Makefiles is necessary by design:

> CMake does not actually generate truly recursive makefiles that follow the directory structure. It generates a fixed 3-level makefile structure in which each level has a defined purpose:
>
> 1. **Makefile:** Command-line interface entry points. Maps "make" invocations into calls to the level 2 makefile:
>
>    - `make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ...`
> 2. **CMakeFiles/Makefile2:** Inter-target dependencies. Evaluates targets in dependency order invoking for each target the depends and build steps in level 3:
>
>    - `make -f CMakeFiles/$(target).dir/build.make .../depend`
>    - `make -f CMakeFiles/$(target).dir/build.make .../build`
> 3. **CMakeFiles/.dir/build.make:** File-level dependencies and rules:
>
>    - `depend:` Evaluates custom commands (to produce generate source files) and then scans sources for implicit dependencies.
>    - `build:` Loads dependency scanning results from previous step. Compiles and links.